# Is there a way to pass a pre-defined date into Google Form with JavaScript

Tags: date, autocomplete, google-forms

Someone please help me to pass a pre-defined date without selecting it in the calendar, pass it into the form below using JavaScript and force the form to recognise it.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGW-7s7hJdqvicsvIxNw426eE3S4XM_PFTfU4wFaqBZnKwfA/viewform

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script>
const date = '2021-07-01';
window.onload = function() {
  googleForm.src = `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfGW-7s7hJdqvicsvIxNw426eE3S4XM_PFTfU4wFaqBZnKwfA/viewform?embedded=true&usp=pp_url&entry.1212265536=${date}`;
};
</script>
```

```html
<iframe id="googleForm" width="640" height="378" frameborder="0" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading…</iframe>
```